# API hosted on aws lambda throws System.IO.IOException: No space left on device : '/tmp/ASPNETCORE_00f99566-f7da-45c6-a51d-6a9218291d21.tmp'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda

we have an asp.net core 6 web api running on aws lambda and it was running fine until yesterday it started throwing the error:
`System.IO.IOException: No space left on device : '/tmp/ASPNETCORE_00f99566-f7da-45c6-a51d-6a9218291d21.tmp'`

the lambda memory is 3GB and the ephemeral storage 512MB, in the largest requests the memory used is usually between 400-600MB and we don't use the ephemeral storage for anything.

Comment: *you* might not be explicitly putting something there, but ASP.NET CORE is.  See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24122.

Comment: yes thank you this was actually the case we were using an inhouse library that buffers the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ASP.NET Core automatically stores data in the /tmp directory.

By default, a Lambda function only provides 512 MB of ephemeral disk space. However, you can increase it in the Lambda function configuration to up to 10 GB.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/